# Ubuntu 12.04 Login Loop (without GUI)

Tags: login

I can't log in to a Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS. Always it loops back to the login (I do not use the GUI!).

One suggestion was to delete the .Xauthority file, but I don't have such a file (and this was more for the GUI login).
In recovery mode I can enter to the root shell.

Do you have any ideas, how to solve the login problem?

Comment: Problems with CLI login are most probably related to something in your shell setup files e.g. `.bashrc` or `.profile`

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the problem myself. It was a problem of increasing ulimit (in my case for using HBase).

What I did:
While startup, I pressed Esc and then choose to start in recovery mode. In the following recovery menu I selected root shell. I moved to my home directory and looked through .bash_history and found what I changed last before the problem occured:

Like in http://hbase.apache.org/book/configuration.html section 2.1.2.5.1. told, I changed the following files:

/etc/security/limits.conf

/etc/pam.d/common-session

I removed the inserted lines for the HBase configuration and the login worked again normally.